# Does a graceful Apache restart clear APC?

Tags: php, apache, apc

Will calling

```
$ httpd graceful
```

clear out the APC cache, or do I have  to do a full-blown

```
$ httpd restart
```

to do it?  (Keeping in mind that I know there are better ways to do it, like calling apc_clear_cache() programmatically).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both will clear APC cache.

You can also clear cache using the APC.php script.

Comment: Does the apc cache also clear the opcode cache, or just the user cache?

Comment: What about an httpd reload ?

Answer (score 6):

Graceful does not wait for active connections to die before doing a "full restart". It is the same as doing a HUP against the master process. Apache keeps children (processes) with active connections alive, whilst bringing up new children with new configuration (or nicely cleared caches) for each new connection. As the old connections die off, those child processes are killed as well to make way for the new ones.

Answer (score 4):

httpd graceful does a full restart, it simply waits until there are no active connections before doing so