# The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! (uncaught exception)

Tags: symfony

I´ve checked already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172586/the-method-name-must-start-with-either-findby-or-findoneby-undefined-method-sym) but my error seems to be different.

I´m getting this error:

```
[2012-05-07 14:09:59] request.CRITICAL: BadMethodCallException: Undefined method 'findOperariosordenados'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! (uncaught exception) at /Users/gitek/www/uda/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php line 201 [] []
```

This is my OperarioRepository:

```
<?php

namespace Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * OperarioRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class OperarioRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOperariosordenados()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $consulta = $em->createQuery('SELECT o FROM GitekUdaBundle:Operario o
                                        ORDER BY o.apellidos, o.nombre');

        return $consulta->getResult();
    }    
}
```

This my controller, where I call the repository:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$operarios = $em->getRepository('GitekUdaBundle:Operario')->findOperariosordenados();
```

Finally, this is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity\Operario
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Operario")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity\OperarioRepository")
 */
class Operario
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nombre
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;
    ----
    ----
```

Any help or clue??

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Works fine on dev environment, but no in prod environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already are in a reposoritory, you do not need to re-get it.

All methods in a *Repository can be used as with `$this`

**Also, note**

- Query Builder or Hand made Query is way too much work when a simple `return $this->findBy();` can be used.
- `findBy()` has three parameters, first is an array of relations and getters, the second is for ordering, see `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` code
- Instead of using Raw queries... try the query builder FIRST. Look at my sample.

**Your code**

I would suggest you simply do:

```
public function findOperariosordenados()
{
    $collection = $this->findBy( array(), array('apellidos','nombre') );
    return $collection;
}
```

You only need `EntityRepository`

**One of my repositories:**

Things to note:

- `Order` has a relationship as `$owner` using the `User` Entity
- If you REALLY need an array, in `$array = $reposiroty->getOneUnhandledContainerCreate(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`
- The `ContainerCreateOrder` is an extend of `Order` in a `@ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")`. Quite out of scope of this question though.

It could be helpful:

```
 <?php

namespace Client\PortalBundle\Entity\Repository;


# Internal
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


# Specific


# Domain objects


# Entities
use Client\PortalBundle\Entity\User;


# Exceptions



/**
 * Order Repository
 *
 *
 * Where to create queries to get details
 * when starting by this Entity to get info from.
 *
 * Possible relationship bridges:
 *  - User $owner Who required the task
 */
class OrderRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    private function _findUnhandledOrderQuery($limit = null)
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
                ->select('o,u')
                ->leftJoin('o.owner', 'u')
                ->orderBy('o.created', 'DESC')
                ->where('o.status = :status')
                ->setParameter('status',
                    OrderStatusFlagValues::CREATED
                )
                ;

        if (is_numeric($limit))
        {
            $q->setMaxResults($limit);
        }
        #die(var_dump( $q->getDQL() ) );
        #die(var_dump( $this->_entityName ) );
        return $q;
    }


    /**
     * Get all orders and attached status specific to an User
     *
     * Returns the full Order object with the
     * attached relationship with the User entity
     * who created it.
     */
    public function findAllByOwner(User $owner)
    {
        return $this->findBy( array('owner'=>$owner->getId()), array('created'=>'DESC') );
    }



    /**
     * Get all orders and attached status specific to an User
     *
     * Returns the full Order object with the
     * attached relationship with the User entity
     * who created it.
     */
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->findBy( array(), array('created'=>'DESC') );
    }



    /**
     * Get next unhandled order
     *
     * @return array|null $order
     */
    public function getOneUnhandledContainerCreate($hydrate = null)
    {
       return $this->_findUnhandledOrderQuery(1)
                    ->orderBy('o.created', 'ASC')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getOneOrNullResult($hydrate);
    }



    /**
     * Get All Unhandled Container Create
     */
    public function getAllUnhandledContainerCreate($hydrate = null)
    {
       return $this->_findUnhandledOrderQuery()
                    ->orderBy('o.created', 'ASC')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult($hydrate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you clear your cache?

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Answer (score 0):

My `app/config/config_prod.yml` has a cache driver specified for doctrine :

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

I cleared APC cache using these function calls :

```
if (function_exists('apcu_clear_cache')) {
    // clear system cache
    apcu_clear_cache();
    // clear user cache
    apcu_clear_cache('user');
}

if (function_exists('apc_clear_cache')) {
    // clear system cache
    apc_clear_cache();
    // clear user cache
    apc_clear_cache('user');
    // clear opcode cache (on old apc versions)
    apc_clear_cache('opcode');
}
```

And emptied `app/cache/` directory.

But I kept getting this error in the prod environment while everything was fine in the dev environment.

I finally rebooted my virtual server and that did the trick.

Which definitely leads me to suspect a cache problem. Next time I will try to (gracefuly) restart the web server only, as that also clears the cache ([php - Does a graceful Apache restart clear APC? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785533/does-a-graceful-apache-restart-clear-apc))

Otherwise, setting `apc.stat = 1` (http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat) in `/etc/php5/apache2php.ini` also seems to be a good idea as suggested here : [do we need to restart apache + APC after new version deployment of app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144350/do-we-need-to-restart-apache-apc-after-new-version-deployment-of-app)

**UPDATE**

My development server has APC installed and not APCu. The first two calls to `apcu_clear_cache()` were causing a PHP Fatal error, which in turn prevented the APC cache from being cleared.

So check which cache your system uses before issuing calls to `apcu_clear_cache()` or `apc_clear_cache()`. After that, no need to restart the virtual machine nor the web server to clear the cache and get rid of the nasty exception.

Addded `if` blocks to run APC or APCu specific functions.